# Change svg image background color on html?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am displaying images dynamically (fetching them from an API). Their background is transparent (alpha). I also have background color I for the images to be on top of on. How would I add this background color to the image on html? I have an Image React class (from Semantic-Ui-React) but ignore this. The attribute of  will work the same. the "fill" and "color" here are just my attempts that didn't work. The rest of the attributes are irrelevant.

```
             <Image
                align="left"
                color="green"
                fill="red"
                src={image}
                size={this.state.tokenImageSize}
                avatar
                onMouseEnter={e =>
                  this.setState({
                    tokenImageSize: "medium",
                    textHeaderSize: "h1"
                  })
                }
                onMouseLeave={e =>
                  this.setState({
                    tokenImageSize: "tiny",
                    textHeaderSize: "h4"
                  })
                }
              />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to change background colours in HTML elements is to use the `style` attribute, and set `background-color` to the colour you need.

For example, you could add to your `<image/>` tag this attribute:

`style='background-color: blue'`

Comment: @Contentop if this has solved your issue, can you please mark it as correct?

Comment: I will mark this as correct altought because it was React and thus JSX I ended up using  style={{ backgroundColor: "blue"}}